# Where should I put Response.AddHeader method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know is a stupid question but I am not expert of it.

I am following the turorial

http://www.joshuawinn.com/fix-html5-validator-error-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-element-meta/

I want to add the code

```
Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1");
```

to my Asp Net MVC project. Where should I put it?

I found this page about it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327(v=vs.90).aspx

that suggests to use

```
<% Response.AddHeader "CustomHeader", "CustomValue" %>
```

But I don't get where I should put it. I already tried

```
<HTML> 
Here's some text on your Web page. 
' This header tells proxy servers using HTTP/1.0 not to cache this request. 
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %> 
<% Response.Flush %>  
<% Response.Write("Pragma is set to no-cache") %>  
</HTML>
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: you could put this in your application - handle the `PostRequestHandlerExecute` event.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting it in the handler, I recommend doing it once for your whole site so you do not need to do it anymore.  You can do it by adding it to your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
           <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
        </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or you can add it as a custom header that is served up by IIS.  Use this page as a guide:

[Add a Custom HTTP Response Header](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the header in the ActionResult that serves your page, for example.:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        return View();
    }
```

If you want this header to be added on more than one request, you could wrap the code in a custom action filter as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176095/mvc-last-chance-to-change-response-before-it-is-rendered-to-user) answer.

Comment: On razor pages core 6 it appears to have been changed to Response.Headers.Add("para", "value")